# REPLACE OR DROP PART OF A STRING

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to drop or replace word(s) in a string.

Example:String = `PINK LENOVO LAPTOP`

Desired output = `LENOVO`

And so, I tried, REPLACE(PINK LENOVO LAPTOP', 'LENOVO'). But of course the out put for that will be:
`PINK LAPTOP`

Any idea how I can drop PINK and LAPTOP or replace the whole string with just `LENOVO`. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT1:**

Just to clarify, I am trying to replace a string of words from a sentence with only one or two words.

So, for example I'd like to replace "PINK LENOVO LAPTOP - i7 16GB RAM" to "LENOVO - i7 16GB RAM"

Comment: do you always want the centre word in that columm

Comment: no, but I am finding a way so that i'll always be able to selectively pick any word in a string.

Comment: Is there always a '-' separator?

Comment: yes. are u thinking of regex..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to how I understand your requirements, it could be this one:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('PINK LENOVO LAPTOP', 'PINK '), ' LAPTOP')
```